# How to enlarge the Text Input field size in Empathy?

Tags: empathy

Is there any way to change the *default* text input field size in empathy windows? I mean, have two or three rows from default, instead of one...

Answer (score 0):

The text field **resizes itself** after entering text more than one row (or when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a line break).

I don't know any option that enables a different default size.